# Edit Message Error of tcxDateEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm using Delphi 7. 
I use the component tCxDateEdit, 
in ValidationOptions , I put the evoRaiseException a false 
the evoshowErrorIcon a true 
When I inser a wrong date like "31/02/2015" , an Icon appear next to my date component and I have a message error like "Date incorrecte" 
there are a way to change the Error  message?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the displayed text in the control's OnValidate event like this

```
procedure TForm1.cxDBDateEdit1PropertiesValidate(Sender: TObject;
  var DisplayValue: Variant; var ErrorText: TCaption; var Error: Boolean);
begin
  ErrorText := DisplayValue + ' is not a valid date';
end;
```